# Why does jenkins mercurial plugin ignore merges?

Tags: mercurial, jenkins, branching-and-merging

I have a Jenkins job watching the 'Live' branch of a mercurial repository. When I merge some changes into Live, commit and push, Jenkins doesn't trigger a build.

Looking at the mercurial polling log you can see

```
$ hg incoming --style <SomeFileUnderWorkspace> --no-merges
```

I can't believe this is a bug, but also can't think of a reason you would want to ignore merges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue. See the following:

[The reason the merges were ignored](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-4972)

[An open issue regarding merges across named branches being ignored](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-7594?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#issue-tabs)

This is annoying in our setup as well. I have to trigger the builds manually when there is a merge.

Comment: According to [the release notes](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mercurial+Plugin), this was fixed in version 1.39 of the plugin.